# Use <img> image as background of another element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Attempted JS

```js
function preview(element) {
  var x = document.getElementById("photos").getElementsByTagName("LI");
  var nodes = document.getElementById(element).childNodes;

  for (i=0; i<x.length; i++){
        x[i].style.width = "10vw";
        x[i].style.height = "10vw";
  }

  document.getElementById('previewBox').style.background = nodes[0];
  viewClose();
}
```

HTML

```html
<ul id = "photos">
    <li onclick="preview('pic1')" id = "pic1">
        <img src = "https://38.media.tumblr.com/d88beaf3fe2964af04e8b3d57aa32e97/tumblr_n9gnc0n0Gu1tgkx81o1_1280.jpg">
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```css
#photos li {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#photos li{
  float: left;
  width: 18vw;
  height: 18vw;
  margin: 1.03vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: black;
}

#photos li > img{
  position: relative;
  bottom: 10px;
  /*-webkit-background-size: cover center center; 
    -moz-background-size: cover; 
    -o-background-size: cover; 
    background-size: cover center center;*/
  width: 140%;
}

#previewBox{
  width: 90vw;
  height: 50vw;
}
```

WHAT I WANT:

Take the `img` from the `li` and make it the background of `#previewBox`.
Nothing seems to really work and I have tried many.(I understand that nodes must have a loop or sub number). Any other approaches? I have learned HTML, CSS, Javascript language, no jquery.

Comment: using the `onclick` attribute is not the best practice to use. As a beginner it's ok for learning, but as soon as you can, learn about abstracting event listeners from your HTML :) `addEventListener` is a function you'll want to intimately know

Comment: You'd have to get the image URL. You can't use a DOM element as CSS property value.

Comment: What are you expecting `document.getElementById('previewBox').style.background = nodes[0];` to do? You can't assign a `Text`/`Node`/`Element` to the `background` property. It'll get converted to string, and the string will probably be `"[object Object]"` or `"[object Node]"` or `"[object Text]"`. Were you looking for `.nodeValue`?

Comment: CSS multiple-background image support is almost universal, also +1 for no jQuery. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.children` instead of `childNodes` to skip text nodes, otherwise you won't get the `img` you're after, you'll get a text node.

As noted elsewhere, you want the *source* of the `img`, not the element itself. And you'll need to wrap that in `url('')`:

```js
function preview(element) {
  var x = document.getElementById("photos").getElementsByTagName("LI");
  var nodes = document.getElementById(element).children;

  for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.width = "10vw";
    x[i].style.height = "10vw";
  }

  document.getElementById('previewBox').style.backgroundImage = "url('" + nodes[0].src + "')";

  viewClose();
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/lokFh

Comment: You can use [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children) instead of `childNodes` to get the first *element* node, thus excluding text nodes.

Comment: I was just in the midst of updating with `children`. :-)

Comment: It works. I cant figure out why it works though. I am new to nodes and dom. Maybe its the terminology? Thanks.